# How can i wait for multiply observables to finish in called order?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, rxjs

When i click on button i am making multiply http request for same api service.
If i want to wait for them i am using async await with promises.

**NOTE THAT THIS METHOD CALL RETURNS OBSERVABLE !**

```
this.getAuctionService.getAllAuctionsUsingPOST
```

```
onButtonClick() {
  makeRequest();
  makeRequest();
  makeRequest();
  makeRequest();
}

makeRequest() {
    try {
          let response: any = this.getAuctionService.getAllAuctionsUsingPOST(params).toPromise()
          this.filterService.auctionTotalPages = response.totalPages;
          this.currentPage = response.currentPage;
          this.remapLazyLoadedData(response, cb);
        } catch (error) {
          this.toastr.error(error.error.description, error.error.error);
        }
}
```

so when i click on the button four http requests are happening in parallel and that means that sometimes the response from httpRequest number 3 can come earlier then the first one, even it was called later.

Because of this problem i am using now async await with promises

```
onButtonClick() {
  await makeRequest();
  await makeRequest();
  await makeRequest();
  await makeRequest();
}

async makeRequest() {
    try {
          let response: any = await this.getAuctionService.getAllAuctionsUsingPOST(params).toPromise()
          ...
        } catch (error) {
          this.toastr.error(error.error.description, error.error.error);
        }
}
```

now i am awaiting each call and the responses of the calls wwill be always in the same order as they were called.

But i can't find solutuion for this with `Observable - rxjs way`

How can i await this multiply calls without async and await ?

```
onButtonClick() {
  makeRequest();
  makeRequest();
  makeRequest();
  makeRequest();
}

makeRequest() {
let response: any = this.getAuctionService.getAllAuctionsUsingPOST(params);
....
}

**what i tried**

i tried with `.subscribe` but it does not work - every each call is not waiting for the previous one
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure where `params` comes from, but here's what I would do with RxJS.

```
private singleRequest$ = this.getAuctionService.getAllAuctionsUsingPOST(params).pipe(
  tap(response=>{
    this.filterService.auctionTotalPages = response.totalPages;
    this.currentPage = response.currentPage;
    this.remapLazyLoadedData(response, cb);
  }),
  catchError(error=>{
    this.toastr.error(error.error.description, error.error.error);
    return EMPTY;
  })
)

private multipleRequests$ = interval(1).pipe(
  takeUntil(i=>i===4),
  concatMap(_=>this.singleRequest$)
)

public onButtonClick(){
  this.multipleRequests$.subscribe();
}
```

First, I declared an observable that calls your service method, and applies new state using the `tap()` operator.

Next, I declare a second counting observable that starts with `0`. Each interval count will call the first observable. Using `concatMap()` ensures each call to your service method happens in order. Our `takeUntil()` operator ensures the observable completes when our counter reaches four.

Thus, your component method just needs to subscribe to `multipleRequests$` to trigger the event. Since `takeUntil()` completes the observable, you don't need to worry about unsubscribing.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single observable that executes multiple in sequence by using [`concat`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat):

```js
const sequential$ = concat(obs1$, obs2$, obs3$);
```

So, if the `makeRequest()` method returned an observable, you could do:

```js
onButtonClick() {
  concat(
    makeRequest(),
    makeRequest(),
    makeRequest(),
    makeRequest()
  )
  .subscribe();
}
```

So `makeRequest` could look like this:

```js
makeRequest() {
  return this.getAuctionService.getAllAuctionsUsingPOST().pipe(
    tap(response => {
      this.filterService.auctionTotalPages = response.totalPages;
      this.currentPage = response.currentPage;
      this.remapLazyLoadedData(response, cb);
    }),
    catchError(({error}) => {
      this.toastr.error(error.description, error.error);
      return EMPTY;
    })
  );
}
```